# Creating Java library file with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: import, intellij-idea, java

I'm trying to create a library which could be used in other projects. I've written one class with several static methods to do some stuff. I wanted to try it out but I am not able to use the imported JAR file.

I have compiled my code as an artifact and took the JAR file from "out" folder and then copied it to another project. After that I went to "Project structure", tab "Libraries" and I pressed the plus button. I've found the JAR file and selected it, afterwards IDEA asked me to specify dependencies so I did, but when I want to use it in code I am not able to do so. It can't even be imported.

[image: Class from library not recognized]

Any ideas why it ignores my library? Thanks!

**What should I do in order to create a JAR library with IntelliJ IDEA, that is usable in other projects?**

Comment: Your description is a little too vague. May I suggest that you download some third party library (v.g., something from Apache Commons) and try to use that in your project? Just to narrow the issue down to creation of the jar or its usage in another project.

Comment: I am all ready using JSch for SSH connection the same way and it works flawlessly. However my library is ignored. I can't use the methods in the main class and I can't create any instances of the class that's in my lib..

Comment: Strange... There is nothing special in creating a JAR library in IDEA and importing it into a project except that you have written (at least in general case). I've just tried to reproduce the steps in your description and had no problems. Try to check if you have not marked accidently your library entirely or in parts as the excluded directory.

Comment: @EugeneEvdokimov I'll check it out. Thanks! Also, should there be a main-class declared if it's a library and users shouldn't be able to execute it as is? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Did you mean `main` method? No, it should not be declared

Comment: What kind of package are you using? Try not to use the default empty package name. Also if you have package, you have to correctly import your class. Also check if it is public, protected, package or private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. When I created the library I was trying to make it simple. Too simple, unfortunately. I had a package with a class in it that was compiled into a JAR. Structure shown below:

```
foo
 |
 |_ MyLib.java
```

However in order to use classes from a created JAR library they have to be placed in packages. That means if I have:

```
foo
 |
 |_bar
 |  |
 |  |_MyInnerLib.java
 |
 |_MyOuterLib.java
```

I am able to import and use methods from MyInnerLib but MyOuterLib isn't reachable nor importable. This was the error I was making.

Comment: Is "foo" the name of your JAR (i.e. it's *foo.jar*)? The reason behind your problem may be this (quote from ["**The Java Language Specification**" section 7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5), emphasis mine): "*A type in an unnamed package (§7.4.2) has no canonical name, so the requirement for a canonical name in every kind of import declaration implies that (a) **types in an unnamed package cannot be imported**, and (b) static members of types in an unnamed package cannot be imported.*".

Answer (score 6):

You are running into a very common dependency management problem.

IMO the real answer is to use a build system like Maven, Ant, or Gradle (I'd go Gradle myself).  What you are trying to do is manual, hard to reproduce, and brittle.

Every time you make a change you will have to go through manual steps to create a new JAR.  And you really don't understand your dependencies.

To go all out with best practices you would be to have real build system that publishes to a continuous integration server, which compiles and runs tests.  On successful completion of the tests, the JARs are published to an artifact server (Nexus/Artifactory).

The people you are sharing with would consume the JARs via the build system by declaring dependencies on your JAR.

Comment: Thanks for the info @phil, it's very useful advice, however I'm not considering any updates on the JAR that I'm trying to create at the moment. The problem is that I am not able to access classes inside of the JAR after import into a project.